# Как перевести отрицательное число из двоичной системы в десятичную?

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Добрейший вечерочек!))

Задание такое: "Ввести последовательность символьных строк (максимально возможное количество строк – NBC), каждая из которых содержит двоичный дополнительный код положительного или отрицательного числа. Затем создать два новых массива: в первый переписать коды положительных чисел, а во второй – отрицательные. Напечатайте две таблицы, в которых указать коды чисел и их десятичные значения. Применить собственную функцию, преобразующую символьную строку, в которой записано двоичный дополнительный код числа (первый бит задает знак), в соответствующее десятичное число"

С положительными числами все ок, но вот отрицательные чет не хочет оно преобразовывать:

```
00011000
Dec: 24
11110100
Dec: 244(а должно быть -12)
00100000
Dec: 32
11000000
Dec: 192(а должно быть -64)
11101100
Dec: 236
10000000
Dec: 128(а должно быть -128)
```

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 10
#define NBC 10

unsigned BinToDec(unsigned Value);
char MinusBin(char* buf);

int main() {

    system("chcp 1251");

    char buf[LEN], //Каждую введенную строку сначала заносим в буфер введения buf
        *pmem;
    char* strpar[NBC], //Адрес сроки, расположенных в динамической памяти, будем сохранять в массиве указателей strpar
        **parp; //Указатель для обращения к strpar
    int nstr, num;

    /* Занесение символьных строк в динамическую память */
    puts("\n\tТекст:");
    nstr = 0, num = 0;
    while (*gets_s(buf) && nstr < NBC) {// пока не введена пустая строка
        pmem = (char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);//выделение места для ДП

    if (pmem == NULL) {
        puts(" Отсутствует свободная память.\n");
        break;
    }
    
    if (buf[0] == '1') {
        MinusBin(buf);
    }
    num = atoi(buf); //переводим строку в число
    printf("Dec: %d\n", BinToDec(num));

    strcpy(pmem, buf); //переносим строку в ДП
    strpar[nstr++] = pmem; // записываем адрес строки в массив
}
strpar[nstr] = NULL; // конец адреса – NULL

/* Освобождение выделенной ДП */
parp = strpar;
while (*parp != NULL) { // цикл по элементам массива указателей
    free(*parp); // стираем строки в ДП
    *parp++ = NULL;
}

return 0;
}

unsigned BinToDec(unsigned Value) {
    unsigned result = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 1; Value; Value /= 10, i *= 2) {
        result += i * (Value % 10);
    }
    return result+1;
}
char MinusBin(char* buf) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++) {
        if (buf[i] == '0') {
            buf[i] = '1';
        }
        else if (buf[i] == '1') {
            buf[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    return *buf;
}
```

Подскажите идеи как модно решить проблему))

P.S.

Есть идея поставить условие что если 1 символ в строке "1", то вызывается еще одна функция и все "0" меняются на "1", и на оборот. И в конце всего этого к новому двоичному числу + 1. Но тогда, как сделать + 1 к новому двоичному коду?

Comment: А просто 1 к результату что мешает прибавить?

Comment: Вы имеете введу уже после преобразования всех 0 в 1 и наоборот, да?

Comment: После получения итогового десятичного числа.

Comment: Да, сделал так как вы и сказали.

Comment: Плюс, я немного пошаманил и сделал доп.функцию для перевода всех 1 в 0, и 0 в 1, если первый символ строки(двоичного кода) - это 1. Сейчас добавлю в код выше, чтобы вы могли посмотреть

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, у вас в тексте примера ошибки с отрицательными числами.  -128 представлено верно, а вот -12 д.б.  1100, 11000000 это -192, а не -64 (-64 это д.б. 1000000) и т.д.

Иначе, (т.е. так, как вы в вопросе их изображаете, "схлопывая" все старшие единички в одну) многие отрицательные значения не могут быть представлены.

Ну, а преобразовывать строку из символов `0` и `1` в целое число, проще всего побитно  формируя его двоичной значение.

```
int
str_tobin (char *s)
{
  int v = 0, 
      neg = (*s == '1') ? -1 : 1, 
      b;

  // бежим по строке до любого символа, отличного от '0' или '1'
  while (b = *s++ - '0', (b == 0 || b == 1)) { 
    v <<= 1;
    v |= b;
  }

  return v * neg;
}
```

Собственно, вот и весь код.